# PowerTop showing BAD status in SATA Link and PCI Device

Tags: battery

I am very new in Linux and had installed recently. The problem which i am facing currently about battery drainage in laptop. So, I read someone where to install powertop and check the status of the Tunables tab. I found few BAD status. Please take a look at the below screenshot. I am using HP DV6 1319tx model.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize each of those settings for low power consumption (`Good`) instead of potentially better performance (`Bad`) by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while they are highlighted in interactive mode.

Alternatively, PowerTOP can automatically tune all settings for low power usage if you run the command

```
sudo powertop --auto-tune
```

Whether the `Good` (lower power usage) or `Bad` (maybe higher performance) settings or a specific combination of those are more suitable for you depends on whether you need long battery life or high performance more. The decision is up to you.