# Buggy powersave in Bionic 18.04

Tags: 18.04, power-management, powertop, tlp

I'm having problems with the powersave mode, I hope someone can help ;D

PREVIEW INFO:
I have installed: tlp, powertop, nvidia privative drivers

1. When I start the laptop on battery mode the graphic performance is laggy (mostly scrolling) but when I start the laptop on AC mode and I disconnect it the performance is good.
2. I noticed that my tunables with powertop doesn't change the state between the battery and AC mode, with Xenial version the tunables changed.
3. I always have four tunables with "Bad" state, one of them is the Nvidia card that if I turn it into "Good" state the laptop save a lot of battery, so I do it each time I go on Battery mode. (I always use intel gpu)

[image: top tunables]

Thanks in advance!

My laptop:

- Dell xps15 9550
- intel i7 6700HQ
- 16GB RAM
- Nvidia 960m

Answer (score 1):

### Auto-tune with `powertop`

From this Q&A: [PowerTop showing BAD status in SATA Link and PCI Device](https://askubuntu.com/questions/916428/powertop-showing-bad-status-in-sata-link-and-pci-device):

> Whether the Good (lower power usage) or Bad (maybe higher performance)
>   settings or a specific combination of those are more suitable for you
>   depends on whether you need long battery life or high performance
>   more. The decision is up to you.

To force all powerTOP settings to "good" when on battery you can use:

```
sudo powertop --auto-tune
```

### tlp by design slows down system on battery power

You have `tlp` installed which [automatically manages many system features](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html). In this case look in your file `/etc/default/tlp` and locate this section:

```
# Set Intel P-state performance: 0..100 (%)
# Limit the max/min P-state to control the power dissipation of the CPU.
# Values are stated as a percentage of the available performance.
# Requires an Intel Core i processor with intel_pstate driver.
#CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_AC=0
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100
#CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_BAT=0
#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=30

# Set the CPU "turbo boost" feature: 0=disable, 1=allow
# Requires an Intel Core i processor.
# Important:
# - This may conflict with your distribution's governor settings
# - A value of 1 does *not* activate boosting, it just allows it
#CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
#CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
```

When you are on AC (plugged into wall) your pstate max percentage is 100 but on Battery it is only 30%.

When you are on AC turbo boost is enabled, when on battery it is disabled.

---

When following the instructions in the link, you may get an error using:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

if so use this instead:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/tlp
```

- Change the line `#CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=30` to `CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=100`
- Change the line `#CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0` to `CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=1`

Save the file and reboot. To save reboot time use `sudo tlp start` instead.

**NOTE:** Changing these settings will improve performance but reduce battery life.

Comment: The thing is that when is on AC and I unplug it and I change the tunables to good. Everything is OK, performance, battery are good so I think is another problem.

Comment: @Buntupana I've just revised answer with powerTOP `--auto-tune` option. If this works for you, the next step is to make permanent: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65948/how-do-i-make-powertops-suggestions-permanent or here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/112705/how-do-i-make-powertop-changes-permanent